# Установка веб-приложения на хостинг (React, Node.js, mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, хостинг, vds

Подскажите пожалуйста, я написал полноценное приложение. 
FrontEnd - React
BackEnd - Node.js + БД - mongoDB

Запускаю и тестирую у себя на компьютере (Linux, Ubuntu 18.04) - все работает отлично.

Как запустить все приложение на хостинге? Читал что для этого нужно арендовать VDS. Возможно напишите где можно прочитать подробное руководство?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий...

Comment: Для начало приобрети площадку..

Comment: Air, о какой площадке идет речь? Вы имеете ввиду арендовать виртуальный сервер (VDS) ?

Comment: Ну ты же сам написал, VDS.

Comment: купишь площадку... Скорее возьмешь в аренду... Получишь IP и пароль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя нет сервер-рендера то не обязательно хостить и фронт и бек в одном месте. Поэтому можно использовать любой файловый хостинг для Реакт билда [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/). Для нодов, нужно уже машину арендовать, но если приложение тестовое и даунтайм не важен, то можно на [heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps) попробовать.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Во всем разобрался, все получилось.